# How can I update react state quick enough in order for the hover effect to feel responsive?

Tags: reactjs, performance

I was wondering if there is a way to make it work. You can check the snippet that I added below.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import Item from "./Item";

export default function App() {
  const [hoveredItem, setHoveredItem] = useState(null);
  const items = [...Array(5000).keys()];

  const handleMouseEnter = (item) => {
    setHoveredItem(item);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {items.map((item) => (
        <Item
          key={item}
          isHover={hoveredItem === item}
          onMouseEnter={() => handleMouseEnter(item)}
        >
          Item {item}
        </Item>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

The code above is just a snippet, using the pseudo class (:hover) wont work for what I need. The id of the item hovered needs to be in the state.

Here is a codesandbox link if you want to play around: https://codesandbox.io/s/floral-cache-wfxws

Comment: You are updating all the items every time your mouse is over one of them. Either use `memo` to limit the update to the one you are hovering and the previous one, or move the over process to the parent, by wrapping your items with a simple div. Also, better use Stackblitz to give an example, codeSandbox does not allow more than 3 sandbox for someone not registered.

Comment: In the app that I'm working on, the Item is in a separate child component and I set the state using Context API. For the child component I already use memo but it still feels quite slow for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do it using hooks:

```js
const [hover, setHover] = useState(false)

return (
    <div>
            <div
                onMouseOver={()=>setHover(true)}
                onMouseOut={()=>setHover(false)}
                className={" " + (hover ? "my-css-class" : "") }>
                My text
            </div>
     </div>
     )
```

Comment: This did helped me a bit by moving the hovered state inside each item. Thank you!